# Get input, and make it appear in html or another input field with jQuery

Tags: jquery, button, input, textfield

How can i make the input of an input textfield appear like output (this may be in another input field or just in html), when a button is clicked?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question is not clear. Please revise, provide example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put in another textbox:

```
$('#outputTextBox').val($('#inputTextBox').val());
```

Append html to a div:

```
$('#outputDiv').append($('#inputTextBox').val());
```

Comment: This is exaclty what i meant! Just needed that .val

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type='text' name='myinput' id='myinput' />
<input type='submit' onclick='return handleSubmit();' />
<div id='myoutput'></div>
```

Then in js:

```
function handleSubmit()
{
    $('#myoutput').append($('#myinput').val())
    return false;
}
```